# Spring Boot: how can @EnableAutoConfiguration be re-used?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Currently I am specifying my Spring Boot auto-configuration excludes in the following way:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { ... })
@ComponentScan("my.company")
class Application {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
    }
}
```

As Spring Boot will be used company-wide, we would like to provide some default configuration classes like `MyCompanyDefaultConfiguration` with some auto-configuration excludes and only specify addition excludes per application if needed.

Something like this:

```
@Import(MyCompanyDefaultConfiguration.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { /* application specific excludes */ })
class Application {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
    }
}

@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { /* company-wide excludes */ })
@ComponentScan("my.company")
class MyCompanyDefaultConfiguration {
    ...
}
```

I've read somewhere that this will not work, as there should be only one `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation per application, because Spring Boot will only consider the one first found. In this case the one on the Application class.

With this restriction in mind, what are the solutions to organize this configuration in a reusable manner?

Answer (score 0):

Make an annotated annotation, like `@EnableAutoConfiguration` itself is an annotated annotation.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { /* application specific excludes */ })
public @interface MyCompanyEnableAutoConfiguration {
}
```

and use it